# How to persist breakpoint in Firebug

Tags: firefox, firebug, breakpoints

I have firebug 1.11.4 and each time a reload the page my breakpoints in the script disappear. Is there a way to persist them so I don't have to set them each time I reload page?

Thanks.

Comment: What Fx version / operating system? Never happened to me, Firebug remembers the breakpoints by default. Does it happen without any edit to the code? Firebug remembers the breakpoints by file name and line number, if you change the code, then remembered line numbers can target empty (non-debuggable) lines etc. so then the breakpoint will not hit.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 11.12. The application that is in question uses ExtJS 4.2 in the UI. I've tried going to other sites with ExtJS and I don't see this problem with re-loading the page. But in this particular application after I reload the page (no code change) the breakpoints disappear. Is it possible there's a setting in this application that removes breakpoints?

Comment: Can you run Firefox in a clean profile (`firefox -P` from command line), install Firebug, and re-try? Are you opening files via `http(s)://` or `file:///`?

Comment: I've also tried that on a different machine (Windows Vista). Firefox version 21. I restarted in clean profile and the breakpoints were gone after re-load. I'm opening the files via http.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the script on the server, you can put a line in :
'debugger' and that will start it.